# How to find most profitable Path in 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, path-finding

I'm trying to implement a game where the viable moves are **down-left** and **down-right**.

The parameter for the function is for the **size** of the *array*, so if you pass `4` it will be a *4 by 4 array*.

The **starting position** is the **top row** from *any column*. Every element in the array is a number in the range `1-100`, taken from a file. I need to find the resulting value for the *most profitable route* from any starting column.

My current implementation will compare the *right position* and *left position* and move to whichever is *higher*. The problem is, for example, if the *left position* is lower in value than the *right*, but the left position will provide more profit in the long run since it can access higher value elements, my *algorithm fails*.

***Here is a demo:***

```
84  (53) 40  62 

*42* 14 [41] 57 

76 *47* 80 [95]
```

If we start at number `53`. The numbers enclosed in `*` are the moves that my algorithm *will take*, but the numbers enclosed in `[]` are the moves my algorithm **should take**.

This is my code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bestPathGame{

    private int[][] grid;
    private int n;
    public bestPathGame(int num){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = num;
        grid = new int[n][n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                grid[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        bestPathGame obj = new bestPathGame(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        obj.bestPath();
    }

    private boolean moveLeftBetter(int r,int c){
        if(c <= 0){
            return false;
        } else if (c >= n -1 ){
            return true;
        }
        return grid[r][c-1] > grid[r][c+1];
    }
    public void bestPath(){
        ArrayList<Integer> allOptions = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
            int row = 0;
            int col = k;
            int collection = grid[row][col];
            while(row < n - 1){
                row += 1;
                if(moveLeftBetter(row,col)){
                    col-=1;
                } else{
                    col+=1;
                }
                collection += grid[row][col];
            }
            allOptions.add(collection);
        }
        System.out.println(allOptions.stream().reduce((a,b)->Integer.max(a,b)).get());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Greedy algorithm vs Dynamic programming

There's an issue with the *logic* of your solution.

Basically, what you are implemented is a called a **greedy algorithm**.  At each step of iteration, you are picking a result that *optimal locally*, assuming that this choice will lead to the *optimal global result*. I.e. your code is based on the assumption that by choosing a *local maximum* between the two columns, you will get the correct *global maximum*.

As a consequence, your code in the `bestPath()` method almost at each iteration will discard a **branch** of paths based on *only one next value*. This approach might lead to incorrect results, especially with large matrixes.

**Greedy algorithms** are rarely able to give an accurate output, usually their result is somewhat close but not precise. As an upper-hand, they run fast, typically in **O(n)** time.

For this problem, you need to use a **dynamic programming** (*DP*).

In short, **DP** is an enhanced *brute-force* approach which *cashes the results* and reuses them instead of recalculating the same values multiple times. And as well, as a regular brute-force **DP** algorithms are always checking *all possible combinations*.

There are two major approaches in *dynamic programming*: **tabulation** and **memoization** ([*take a look at this post for more information*](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/tabulation-vs-memoization)).

#### Tabulation

While implementing a **tabulation** first you need to create an *array* which then need to be prepopulated (completely or partially). *Tabulation* is also called the ***bottom-up approach*** because calculation start from the elementary *edge cases*. Every possible outcome is being computed based on the previously obtained values while iterating over this array. The final *result* will usually be stored in the last cell (*in this case in the last row*).

To implement the **tabulation**, we need to create the matrix of the same size, and copy all the values from the given matrix into it. Then row by row every cell will be populated with the maximum possible profit that could be obtained by reaching this cell from the first row.

I.e. every iteration will produce a solution for a *2D-array*, that continuously increases by one row at each step. It'll start from the array that consists of only one first row (*no changes are needed*), then to get the profit for every cell in the second row it's values has to be combined with the best values from the first row (that will be a valid solution for 2D-array of size `2 * n`), and so on. That way, solution gradually develops, and the last row will contain the maximum results for every cell.

That how the code will look like:

```
public static int getMaxProfitTabulation(int[][] matrix) {
    int[][] tab = new int[matrix.length][matrix.length];
    for (int row = 0; row < tab.length; row++) { // populating the tab to preserve the matrix intact
        tab[row] = Arrays.copyOf(matrix[row], matrix[row].length);
    }

    for (int row = 1; row < tab.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < tab[row].length; col++) {
            if (col == 0) { // index on the left is invalid
                tab[row][col] += tab[row - 1][col + 1];
            } else if (col == matrix[row].length - 1) { // index on the right is invalid
                tab[row][col] += tab[row - 1][col - 1];
            } else {
                tab[row][col] += Math.max(tab[row - 1][col - 1], tab[row - 1][col + 1]); // max between left and right
            }
        }
    }
    return getMax(tab);
}
```

Helper method responsible for extracting the *maximum* value from the ***last row*** (*if you want to utilize streams for that, use* `IntStream.of(tab[tab.length - 1]).max().orElse(-1);`).

```
public static int getMax(int[][] tab) {
    int result = -1;
    for (int col = 0; col < tab[tab.length - 1].length; col++) {
        result = Math.max(tab[tab.length - 1][col], result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

#### Memoization

The second option is to use **Memoization**, also called the ***top-down*** approach.

As I said, **DP** is an improved brute-force algorithm and **memoization** is based on the recursive solution that generates all possible outcomes, that is enhanced by adding a `HashMap` that stores all previously calculated results for every cell (i.e. previously encountered unique combination of *row* and *column*).

Recursion starts with the first row and the **base-case** of recursion (*condition that terminates the recursion and is represented by a simple edge-case for which output is known in advance*) for this task is when the recursive call hits the last row `row == matrix.length - 1`.

Otherwise, `HashMap` will be checked whether it already contains a result. And if it not the case all possible combination will be evaluated and the best result will be placed into the `HashMap` in order to be reused, and only the then the method returns.

Note that **tabulation** is usually preferred over **memoization**, because recursion has significant limitations, especially in Java. But recursive solutions are sometimes easier to came up with, so it's completely OK to use it when you need to test the idea or to prove that an iterative solution is working correctly.

The implementation will look like that.

```
public static int getMaxProfitMemoization(int[][] matrix) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
        result = Math.max(result, maxProfitHelper(matrix, 0, i, new HashMap<>()));
    }
    return result;
}

public static int maxProfitHelper(int[][] matrix, int row, int col,
                                  Map<String, Integer> memo) {
    if (row == matrix.length - 1) { // base case
        return matrix[row][col];
    }

    String key = getKey(row, col);
    if (memo.containsKey(key)) { // if cell was already encountered result will be reused
        return memo.get(key);
    }

    int result = matrix[row][col]; // otherwise result needs to be calculated
    if (col == matrix[row].length - 1) { // index on the right is invalid
        result += maxProfitHelper(matrix, row + 1, col - 1, memo);
    } else if (col == 0) { // index on the left is invalid
        result += maxProfitHelper(matrix, row + 1, col + 1, memo);
    } else {
        result += Math.max(maxProfitHelper(matrix, row + 1, col - 1, memo),
                           maxProfitHelper(matrix, row + 1, col + 1, memo));
    }
    memo.put(key, result); // placing result in the map
    return memo.get(key);
}

public static String getKey(int row, int col) {
    return row + " " + col;
}
```

Method `main()` and a *matrix-generator* used for testing purposes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = generateMatrix(100, new Random());

    System.out.println("Tabulation: " + getMaxProfitTabulation(matrix));
    System.out.println("Memoization: " + getMaxProfitMemoization(matrix));
}

public static int[][] generateMatrix(int size, Random random) {
    int[][] result = new int[size][size];
    for (int row = 0; row < result.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < result[row].length; col++) {
            result[row][col] = random.nextInt(1, 101);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: An incredible response! I'm immensely appreicative, you packed so much knowledge in your answer. This was really great, thanks!